# Adding Ng directives to Dynamically Created Buttons

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular13

The goal of this code is to dynamically generate ng-containers that generate buttons with classes that either is active or inactive depending on a user's permissions list. Due to limitations currently, I can not retrieve the permissions list and need to create the buttons before the permissions list is pulled from the user token.

I am trying to create buttons on the OnInit() for the component, which has a series of ng-templates that are chosen between via ngIf directives according to the users permissions map which is stored locally.

I have looked around and understand that directives need to be compiled, but was wondering if there are any tricks or help I can be pointed to as my search has only pulled up common references to it not being possible or tricks that require already generating part of the html.

component.ts

```
import { KeyValuePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Route } from '@angular/router';
import { createPopper } from '@popperjs/core';
import * as libs from '../../../../assets/jsonFiles/libs.json';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-libs-view',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  templateUrl: './libs-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./libs-view.component.css']
})
export class LibsViewComponent implements OnInit {

  hasLibraryAccess = new Map<String, boolean>();
  constructor(route: ActivatedRoute) {  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.formatLibraryButtons()
  }

  formatLibraryButtons() {
    let btnLayoutHlpr = 0;

    // hard coded for now to test the original 12 buttons
    // should read json and get each library, and create a button correctly for it
    for (let eachLib in Libs) {
      let lib = Libs[eachLib].Name
      console.log(lib)
      // https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/dom-manipulation.html
      if (btnLayoutHlpr < 2) {
        const btnGrp = document.getElementById("btnGrp1");
        //this.createButton(btnGrp!, lib)
        ++btnLayoutHlpr;
      } else if (btnLayoutHlpr < 4) {
        const btnGrp = document.getElementById("btnGrp2");
        //this.createButton(btnGrp!, lib)
        ++btnLayoutHlpr
      } else if (btnLayoutHlpr < 6) {
        const btnGrp = document.getElementById("btnGrp3");
        //this.createButton(btnGrp!, lib)
        ++btnLayoutHlpr
      } else if (btnLayoutHlpr < 9) {
        const btnGrp = document.getElementById("btnGrp4");
        //this.createButton(btnGrp!, lib)
        ++btnLayoutHlpr
      } else if (btnLayoutHlpr < 12) {
        const btnGrp = document.getElementById("btnGrp5");
        //this.createButton(btnGrp!, lib)
        ++btnLayoutHlpr
      } else {
        //console.log("check")
        ++btnLayoutHlpr
      }

     // setting all to true for dev purposes
      this.hasLibraryAccess.set(lib, true); all library names must start lowercase or angular's auto-sort method messes up btn placement

    }
    console.log("Button creation complete")
    console.log("Library Access Map Created")
 }

  createButton(btnGrp : Element, lib: string) {
    // create ng-content div to hold logic for if library is accessible
    const ngCont = document.createElement("ng-container")
    
    // create ngIf for checking if customer has access to library
    const ngIf = document.createElement("div")
    //ngIf add ngIf to the div such that ngIf=libraryAccess.value | then libAccessTrue else libAccessFalse
    ngCont.appendChild(ngIf)
    
   // create first template to add library access button
    const ngTemp = document.createElement("ng-template")
    //ngTemp.add add #LibraryAccessTrue

    // create div wrapper for btn
    const divWrapper = document.createElement("div")
    divWrapper.style.marginLeft = "1 px";

    // create accessible btn and add it to  divWrapper and add divWrp to template
    const libBtn = document.createElement("a");
    libBtn.classList.add('hexagon', 'd-flex', 'align-self-center');
    libBtn.textContent = lib;
    divWrapper.appendChild(libBtn)
    ngTemp.appendChild(divWrapper)
    
    // add first template for accessible library button to ng-content
    ngCont.appendChild(ngTemp);

    // create second template to add library access button
    const ngTemp2 = document.createElement("ng-template")
    //ngTemp.add add #LibraryAccessTrue

    // create second div wrapper for btn
    const divWrapper2 = document.createElement("div")
    divWrapper2.style.marginLeft = "1 px";

    // create disabled btn and add it to its divWrapper then to template
    const libBtn2 = document.createElement("a");
    libBtn2.classList.add('hexagon-disabled', 'd-flex', 'align-self-center');
    libBtn2.textContent = lib;
    divWrapper2.appendChild(libBtn2)
    ngTemp2.appendChild(divWrapper2)
    
    // add second template for disabled library button to ng-content
    ngCont.appendChild(ngTemp2);

    // add the entire ng-content div to the button group
    btnGrp?.appendChild(ngCont);
  }

}
```

component.html

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="container parent-hexagon">
    <div class="d-inline-block" style="margin-left: 8%; width: 80%">

      <div id="btnGrp1" class="btn-toolbar">
        <div *ngFor="let libraryAccess of hasLibraryAccess | keyvalue">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="btnGrp2" class="btn-toolbar" style="margin-left: 12%">
        <div *ngFor="let libraryAccess of hasLibraryAccess | keyvalue">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="btnGrp3" class="btn-toolbar">
        <div *ngFor="let libraryAccess of hasLibraryAccess | keyvalue">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="btnGrp4" class="btn-toolbar" style="margin-left: 12%">
        <div *ngFor="let libraryAccess of hasLibraryAccess | keyvalue">

        </div>
      </div>

      <div id="btnGrp5" class="btn-toolbar" style="margin-left: 24.25%">
        <div *ngFor="let libraryAccess of hasLibraryAccess | keyvalue">
          
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

component.css

```
.parent-hexagon {
  max-width: 90%;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 42vh;
  background: green;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
}

  .parent-hexagon::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -20vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 20vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20vh solid green;
  }

  .parent-hexagon::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 20vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 20vw solid transparent;
    border-top: 25vh solid green;
  }

.hexagon {
  width: 7.5vw;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 8.5vh;
  color: black;
  font-size: 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #bfe8f7;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 28.865px;
}

  .hexagon::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -28.8675px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 28.8675px solid #bfe8f7;
  }

  .hexagon::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -28.8675px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-top: 28.8675px solid #bfe8f7;
  }

  .hexagon:hover {
    background: #7fd1ef;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: scale(1.15)
  }

    .hexagon:hover:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -28.8675px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 29.8675px solid #7fd1ef;
    }

    .hexagon:hover:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -28.8675px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-top: 29.8675px solid #7fd1ef;
    }

.hexagon-disabled {
  width: 7.5vw;
  height: 8.5vh;
  color: black;
  font-size: 90%;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: #caced0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 28.865px;
}

  .hexagon-disabled::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: -28.8675px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 28.8675px solid #caced0;
  }

  .hexagon-disabled::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -28.8675px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
    border-top: 28.8675px solid #caced0;
  }


  .hexagon-disabled:hover {
    background: #caced0;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: scale(1.15)
  }

    .hexagon-disabled:hover:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      top: -28.8675px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 29.8675px solid #caced0;
    }

    .hexagon-disabled:hover:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -28.8675px;
      left: 0;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-right: 3.75vw solid transparent;
      border-top: 29.8675px solid #caced0;
    }
```

As shown above, the issue is the html is pretty sparse beyond setting up the button groups and the ngFor directives to iterate the libraryAccessPermissions map that tells the ng-containers being dynamically created which ng-template to show. If I could get the permissions, I would forgo the ngIf and just generate the buttons with css classes dependent on their permissions. But since they won't, for project reasons, be given till after the components Init(), I have to create templates and a permission map to track and properly show buttons.

Any help on how to generate these buttons would be welcome and grateful for.

Comment: use ngClass. https://appdividend.com/2022/02/16/angular-ngclass/ and https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ngclass-ngstyle/

Answer (score 0):

no,no,no,no...

We are using Angular. Angular is related to use variables in .ts and show data in the .html. So you need "think in variables"

Imagine a variable like

```
groupButtons=[
   [{text:"one",level:0},{text:"two",level:1}],
   [{text:"three",level:0},{text:"four",level:0}],
   [{text:"five",level:99}]
]
user={name:"USER 1",level:99} //I imagine a variable "user"
```

You can easy use *ngFor and *ngIf (see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives))

```
 to write
<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="container parent-hexagon">
    <div class="d-inline-block" style="margin-left: 8%; width: 80%">
       <!--iterate over group-->
       <!--see how use [style.margin-left] to add the margin-left 
           to all the groups else the first
           BTW, Why not use justify-content:space-between?
       -->
       <div *ngFor="group of groupButtons;let first=first" class="btn-toolbar"
          [style.margin-left]="first?null:'12%'">

            <!--the second loop-->
            <ng-container *ngFor="button of group">
             
              <div class="wrapper">
                 <!--the "a" is disabled if user.level<button.level"-->
                 <a [class.hexagon-disabled]="user.level<button.level"

                    <!--only execute "doSomething" if user.level>=button.level-->

                    (click)="user.level>=button.level && doSomething(button)"> 
                    {{button.text}}
                 </a>
              </div>
            </ng-container>
       </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

See that you not create buttons in the javascript way, else allow Angular show the buttons (and add classes) using variables

NOTE: It's only an example

Comment: Thank you for the help. The margin being 8% is actually setting up the different btn groups. The buttons are in a tessellating pattern that isn't shown by code alone.

So with the groupbuttons, this is where I would read in the json of buttons needed to be created? Then using this information, in the html can have the for loop create these buttons. I am following the code, but probably need to apply it to better see it.

The problem being that my tasks states the number of buttons can grow at any time and using docker, is trying to prevent downtime due to rebuilding. Thank you again.